# I may be stupid but I can't find my terminal window, I just installed version 12.04.3, Help

Tags: command-line

I can't find my terminal window, I just installed version 12.04.3, Help..

Answer (score 3):

Try pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to bring up terminal.

Alternatively, you can press the Windows key (which brings up a search area), and type Terminal which should show you the Terminal icon. Click on it and Terminal should show up.